# Bug with NSString componentsSeparatedByString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I've been trying to read sections of a string into an array and encountered some problems. Though my task is more complicated, even a simple example case like the one below gives the same problem: the code compiles and runs but the the size of the strings array is always one and the only thing that's contained in strings[0] is "__NSArrayM".

```
NSString *string = @"John, Bob, Jane";
NSArray *strings = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 6):

When you say "the size of the strings array", do you mean what you get from `[strings count]` or something else? Also, Objective-C doesn't let you access NSArray elements with the square bracket notation, so if you're literally calling `strings[0]` you're doing some pointer math on the Array object that you don't intend to be doing.

Comment: +1 That `strings[0]` bit is absolutely a no-go. `[strings count]` will give you the number of elements in the array, and `[strings objectAtIndex:0]` will give you the first element.